# Как сделать тест, в конце выводился бы правильный результат в виде профессии?

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу сделать тест на профориентацию, в котором были бы вопросы и в конце в виде результата выводилась бы профессия. Я хочу выводить профессии в соответствии с максимальным из тех шести значений. Но проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно найти максимальное значение из шести значений. Но я не знаю, как можно сравнить и найти максимальное значение из этих шести, если они находятся в разных активити. Вместе с этим, эти значения всегда разые, то есть изменяемые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить данные по итогу, я могу предложить использование синглтона. Создаете объект:

```
object GeneralClass {
var answers:ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
}
```

в этом классе будет массив с вашими цифрами. Другой вариант это использовать `HashMap` где ключ это будет активность, а значение это результат вашего ответа:

```
var answers = HashMap<Int, Int>()
```

Для записи используем:

```
GeneralClass.answers.add(ваш ответ)
```

Дальше используя `Collections` можно извлечь максимальное значение из сохраненного массива:

```
Collections.max(GeneralClass.answers);
```

**P.S. Чтобы людям было проще дать вам ответ, предоставляйте хоть какой-то код. Например что и как вы делаете в активности.**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.